# How to get sum of indexed in array

Tags: c++, arrays

Having array of ints i was woundering is it possible to get, sum of indexes in desired range?

```
int pointX[LENGHT] = {0,531,710,1067,1537,1903,2121,2434,2738,3031,...};
```

say i want to get number of indexes 4 each side for value =  1903 as int.
so... i am looking to have something like:

```
x0 = 6
xN1 = 5
```

(xN1 - x-1 position from looked number)

```
xN2 = 4
xN3 = 3
xN4 = 2
```

(for positive numbers in array)

```
x1 = 7
x2 = 8
```

...and so on.
so as sum i could have:

```
sum = xN4 + xN3 + xN2 + xN1 + x + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4;
```

UPDATE:

in above array 0 has index 0, 531 has index 1 and soo on. Now how to get index into int? I would like to have index of say 531 put into

```
int x;
```

how to do it?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you're asking for.

Comment: not clear at all what you want to do. You lost me already after "sum of indexes", because for me sum of index from eg. 2 to 5 is 2+3+4+5

Comment: @tobi303 They probably meant to sum up `pointX[2] + pointX[3]  + pointX[4]  + pointX[5] `. But beyond that, I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ probably, but while reading on I just got more confused...

Comment: @tobi303 no, `pointX[2]` will give you value of that index, i want to have index number into int.

Comment: @cheeroke So you want to find a specific value and get back the index?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - yes, it is as simple as getting `i` so having explicite values i can get index by calling for `i` of that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the index of an element (e.g. 531) in the array you can use `std::find` :

```
auto result1 = std::find(std::begin(pointX), std::end(pointX), 531);
```

This returns an iterator to the first occurence of 531 in the array and you can get the index (or -1 if the element was not found) via

```
int index = (result1 == std::end(pointX)) ? -1 : std::begin(pointX) - result1;
```

PS: this answers the question in your UPDATE, however, I still dont really understand what the rest of the question is about (no offense, if your english is not so good, just keep trying ;).

Comment: @Gibet both `std::find` and `std::lower_bound` return the first element they find, so I dont understand what this has to do with the array being sorted. Also `std::lower_bound` is searching for an element greater or equal while OP was asking for equal.

Comment: @Gibet well ok I got it, `std::lower_bound` is supossed to be slightly more efficient (log2 instead of linear complexity). However I doubt that there would be notable difference for not too large `LENGTH`, but of course worth trying out

Comment: @Gibet I would bet that a linear search wins for small array sizes even on a sorted array, but I am not sure, I will try it out.